# Publishing web app from Visual Studio doesn't update views

Tags: asp.net-core, deployment, ftp, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to publish changes to a .NET Core 3.1 web app from Visual Studio 2019 using FTP, however the process doesn't update my .cshtml views.

The app works properly on my local machine, I deleted the contents of the 'bin' directory before publishing, and my publish settings delete all of the existing files on the server before copying new ones over, so this process appears to be somehow copying over views which are no longer available anywhere?! I've not changed any of the 'build action' properties and most of the configuration in Startup is the default MVC template.

Microsoft docs reference a NuGet package (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation) and using AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() in Startup, but this didn't seem to have any effect.

I find it incredibly bizarre that views aren't updated during a publish by default. I also find it bizarre that in this day and age SFTP appears to be unsupported (wth). Hopefully I'm just doing something wrong rather than this process being silly. Any ideas?

[image: SFTP warning]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the Kestrel service used by my server seems to have resolved it...there has to be a more obvious solution though as this method requires shell access.